# Replacing CodeCommit with Git in existing aws pileline

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have an aws pipeline with code commit as it's repo.

What I am trying to achieve is to change the repo to my existing git repo in the pipeline.
Is there a way to achieve it? The documents I am referring to shows how to mirror the contents of git repo to local and then push it to the code commit.

That doesn't fit in with the use case.
I am aiming for something like git which would act as source control in the AWS pipeline and any commit in that will trigger a build.

Could anyone suggest to me if we could achieve this? Or  build a pipeline with git repo

Comment: What solution are using for Git atthe moment?

Comment: current using codecommit in place of git.
basically have followed this doc till now :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html

Comment: So CodeCommit is a managed service for hosting git repositories as the remote. What did you want to replace it with, another managed service such as GitHub or Bitbucket, or perhaps a remote that is hosted locally?

Comment: I am to replace it with existing git repo

Comment: OK, but where is that Git repo hosted? :)

Comment: Under companies Github account

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I am missing anything

Comment: @ChrisWilliams could you please help me out with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985504/returning-only-the-subset-for-response-from-dynamdb-scan?noredirect=1#comment114891954_64985504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePipeline has a few options for the Source of the pipeline, for a Git style deployment there is:

- [CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeCommit.html)
- [GitHub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html)
- [CodeStarSourceConnection (Bitbucket)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html)

These options will trigger the pipeline if a specific branch within your repository receives additional changes, taking an archive of the code at the latest changes.

In addition if you require multiple branches you take a look at using the [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-S3.html) combined with some automation to push the code from any branch to S3 which would trigger the CodePipeline. Alternatively create multiple pipelines if you have a select few branches which must be deployed regularly.