# Returning only the subset for response from dynamdb scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

the use case that I am trying to achieve is:

To check if there is any existing bid on the load that has been posted.

there 2 different tables

1. "load" which has information on the load
2. "bid" which has information of bid on loads.

Now I read that dynamodb can't support joins as RDS does.

How can I check there is an exiting bid on a load?

My approach here was to scan the "bid" table with load_id and bid_by and send the information to the front end and do the rest of the operation there.

here is a code snippet:

```
dynamo_client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
loadeo_loadBoard = dynamo_client.Table('loadeo_bid')

load_id = event['queryStringParameters']['load_id']
company_name = event['queryStringParameters']['companyName']

response = loadeo_loadBoard.scan(
    FilterExpression = Attr('posted_by_company').eq(company_name) & Attr('load_id').eq(load_id)
    )
#sending to sendResponse function as the response generated by scan will have nested json 
return sendResponse(response,company_name)
```

Here I need to send only the load_id and the bid_amount present in "bid" table, is there a way I can achieve that?

and also is there a way I can achieve joins for my use case?

Comment: `scan` is very inefficient and costly. Have you considered using indices to use `query` rather then `scan`?

Comment: To use query I need to use key attribute or have a global secondary index.

Comment: The query can be used on primary table if you have sort key. But if you want to use GSI, you could sparse indices. So any load with existing bid would be present in GSI, otherwise its not present.

Comment: the reason that I am using scan is that I am querying the table based on attribute not  any of the keys

Comment: I see. So maybe sparse GSI could be worth considering?

Comment: not sure if it will work in my use case. which has two different table to look for